# Parameterize() must be of the type array, string given in Laravel 5.2

Tags: arrays, json, laravel-5

i am using laravel 5.2 and trying to update records using `whereIn('id',[1,2])` but when i try to pass a json value [1,2] to it , i returns 
**parameterize() must be of the type array, string given.** I am mentioning my code below.

```
$load_id=json_encode($request->chk_load,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); // it returns [1,2]

Load::whereIn('id',$load_id)->update(array('status'=>3));
```

What should i do to fix this error. ?

Answer (score 0):

seems `json_encode($request->chk_load,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`
returns json string and not an array..

can you elaboarate `$request->chk_load` is what kind of data it is?

Comment: it is an array('0'=>'1','1'=>'2')

Comment: give a try with


`$arr = $request->input('chk_load');
Load::whereIn('id',$arr)->update(array('status'=>3));`

Comment: I think there is no difference between $request->chk_load and $request->input('chk_load')

Comment: basically json_encode will not do since it will return data type as json string..It will look for array..